# MC34072 maximum drawn current

Tags: operational-amplifier, datasheet

How much current can this [MC34072](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=MC34072) op-amp deliver on the output? Not 100% sure on where to find it in the datasheet.. But is it on page 11 in the pdf document, where the graph shows supply current vs supply voltage?

Comment: So you are not looking for "Output Short Circuit Current" ?

Comment: Maybe it is, is that how much current the op-amp can manage to deliver?

Comment: The figures for output swing are quoted for 10K and 2k loads so this would indicate its happy to supply (source/sink) at least 7 - 8 mA . The S/C output source/sink current is around the 30mA mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output short circuit current is 30 mA (worst case) on page 4 of the ON semi data sheet. Typically it might be 20 mA and varies a bit between sinking and sourcing. Also take a look at figure 13. The figure tends to contradict the table on page 6 so maybe test one if it is important.